# Make Firefox warn before allowing user to visit non-HTTPS website

Tags: firefox, security, https

I want to avoid accidentally visiting websites served over unencrypted HTTP.

How can I configure Firefox so that it will warn me if I attempt to visit such a site?

Ideally:

- this shouldn't need an add-on, but if that's the only way you can find to achieve it, then please explain that approach.
- the warning will be similar to that which Firefox gives if I attempt to visit a site, served over HTTPS, whose certificate has expired or is otherwise untrusted, i.e. hard to miss!

Comment: HTTPS Everywhere is a great add-on, but it does ***not*** do what I asked for in my question. It does something quite different, which is to ensure that requests are made over HTTPS where the EFF knows HTTPS to be available.

Comment: Didn't mean to sound harsh, but it wasn't a very helpful comment. "How can I do X?" "Here's how to do Y." Thanks for trying, though: I appreciate the good intention. Ideally, I would like to avoid writing an entire add-on: if I wanted to do that, I'd have asked at StackOverflow or similar :)

Comment: Fine; I will delete my comment; This can only be done with an add-on

Comment: Thanks; my question may also be read as, "Does an effective Firefox add-on for this already exist, and if so, what is it called?"

Comment: That would make your question off-topic, so surely, that's not what you're asking.

Comment: @fixer1234, that's not a constructive remark, sorry. Installing an add-on (and setting its options, if necessary) is *one* way of configuring Firefox. If I knew in advance whether it was the only adequate way, or which relevant add-ons existed and the extent to which they needed tweaking after installation in order to achieve the desired behaviour, then not only would I be able to judge precisely how pedantically those actions fall within the scope acceptable to ask about here, I also would not have needed to ask the question because I would already have known the answer.

Comment: @fixer1234, if you think the question is more appropriate at a different site on SE, feel free to ask a mod to move it to that SE site. Thanks. Please note that this question now has an answer, so is likely to be helpful to any other SuperUsers seeking to elicit the same behaviour from Firefox. Therefore, as a benefit to the community, please do not vote to close/delete it.

Comment: You misunderstood my comment.  I think your question is fine as-is.  However, explicitly asking for a software recommendation would make it off topic (and someone already voted to close on that basis).  I was suggesting that you not advertize that a software rec was the intent of your question.  There is nothing wrong with people recommending software as a solution, though.  Maybe I should have ended my tongue-in-cheek comment with a smilely face.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234, glad you agree my question is fine, & thanks for the support :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the [uBlock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/) add-on.

Go to the uBlock Origin dashboard and click on the "My filters" tab.

(Alternatively, paste this into FireFox's address bar and then hit enter: `chrome://ublock0/content/dashboard.html#1p-filters.html` .)

Add the following rule on a line by itself

```
http://*
```

Click the "Apply changes" button. Done!